# E4 get active perspective ID or label

Tags: java, perspective, e4

i am building a switcher for perspectives. i want to use one button for it. so that when i click one time it switches to perspective2 and when i cklick second time it switches back to perspective1. i try isOnTop but it is not working. Please help. thank you.

```
public class SwitchPerspectiveHandler {
@Execute
public void execute(MApplication app, EPartService partService, EModelService modelService) {
    MPerspective xxx = (MPerspective) modelService.find("xxx",   app);
    MPerspective yyy = (MPerspective) modelService.find("yyy", app);

    if (yyy.isOnTop()) {
        partService.switchPerspective(xxx);
    } else
        partService.switchPerspective(yyy);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The `EModelService` has:

```
public MPerspective getActivePerspective(MWindow window);
```

You can find the `MWindow` with:

```
public MWindow getTopLevelWindowFor(MUIElement element);
```

where `element` is any element in the window.